# Corrupted audio when playing incomplete avi files

Tags: linux, debian, vlc-media-player

With VLC player one can watch an `avi` file while still downloading, after the opening the not yet fully downloaded file, the message appears and you choose "Play as is".

On Linux Mint it works fine, however, when I do it on my Debian system, the avi file plays, but the sound is badly corrupted. I imagine it might be some codecs Linux Mint has in the box but Debian doesn't, but I don't know which and how to get them.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: It could be that the part of the file responsible for the audio is not yet downloaded. I'm voting to close this as far too broad to answer correctly.

Comment: @Burgi I believe this is not true since same files can be watched just fine on Linux Mint (still not fully downloaded). Only Debian has this sound issue. If the issue was in the file I download, the issue would occur on Linux Mint too, but it does not.

Comment: Does Debian play the file without problems if you wait until downloading is finished?

Comment: @fixer1234 yes, after download everything works great.